# python json dump extra brackets

Tags: python, json

I'm using Python 2.7's `json.dumps` to post data to a website:

```
v = json.dump({'addresses.address': '123 Main St', 'addresses.city': 'Somewhere'})
```

If I print out the data, it looks fine:

```
{'addresses.address': '123 Main St', 'addresses.city': 'Somewhere'}
```

but once its posted via

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=v, verify=False)
```

it add extra info to the request:

```
{"{'addresses.address': '123 Main St', 'addresses.city': 'Somewhere'}"=>nil}
```

Comment: if you use `requests`, just send the data with the dictionary, no need to `json.dumps(...)`.

Comment: If the answer resolved your question please accept the answer for the benefit of other people on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the dictionary directly to `json`:

```
v = {'addresses.address': '123 Main St', 'addresses.city': 'Somewhere'}
requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=v, verify=False)
```

This is possible as of requests 2.4.3.

Comment: but it became something like:
{'addresses.address'=>'123 Main St', 'addresses.city'=> 'Somewhere'}
=> instead of :